# How can I toggle hidden/unhidden in Bootstrap without using toggle

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am well on my way to making my first Bootstrap website, and I recently ran into the first problem that google couldn't help me with.
I am searching for a way to set **div** elements to hidden/unhidden without the use of toggle. I have a pretty nice website going, and it has three large "buttons" created from some evenly spaced photos. I have three divs, each default hidden. Clicking on each photo should unhide a corresponding div, while insuring the other two are hidden. For example, clicking on "3D modeling"-image should toggle it either hidden/unhidden, while also insuring my other two portfolio sections are still closed.

I can easily handle the clicked-upon section by using toggle, but its not so simple when handling the other two. For example, all three start closed, (C C C) I then click the first one (O C C) then the second one (O O C). This means both of them are open.

This is just psudo-code, but this is more or less what I want:

```
onImageOneClick{
   DivOne.setHidden(false);
   DivTwo.setHidden(true);
   DivThree.setHidden(true);
}

onImageTwoClick{
   DivOne.setHidden(true);
   DivTwo.setHidden(false);
   DivThree.setHidden(true);
}

onImageTwoClick{
   DivOne.setHidden(true);
   DivTwo.setHidden(true);
   DivThree.setHidden(false);
}
```

This is instead my current code:

```
<script>
  $("#thumb1").click(function(){
    $("#3DModel").toggleClass("hidden unhidden");
  });
  $("#thumb2").click(function(){
    $("#DigitalArt").toggleClass("hidden unhidden");
  });
  $("#thumb3").click(function(){
    $("#WebDesign").toggleClass("hidden unhidden");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: There are also the jquery methods .hide() and .show()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the div's you want to show and hide have a .showable class, and that .hidden class hides the element (I don't think you need both hidden and unhidden classes):

```
<script>
$("#thumb1").click(function(){
    $(".showable").addClass("hidden");
    $("#3DModel").removeClass("hidden");

});
$("#thumb2").click(function(){ 
    $(".showable").addClass("hidden");
    $("#DigitalArt").removeClass("hidden");
});
$("#thumb3").click(function(){
    $(".showable").addClass("hidden");
    $("#WebDesign").removeClass("hidden");
});
</script>
```

In every click, you just hide all the elements and then show (by removing .hidden) the element you want to show. I think this is that you want to achieve in your pseudo-code, but even if I understood bad and you need a different solution, I think $.addClass() and $.removeClass() will serve you.

Answer (score 0):

You can call this javascript function everytime the 3 buttons are click

```
function process(id) {
     var divID = "#" + id;

     if($(divID).css("display") === "block")
        $(divID).css("display", "none");
     else
        $(divID).css("display", "block");
}
```

then on the buttons assign this onclick='process([DivID])'
replace the [DivID] with the div ID you wish to hide or unhide